# Obtain values from Shiny context from cmd

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am looking to get the values from a reactive function, based on a specific set of inputs, but without the dashboard open or visible. Is this possible?

I have two possible solutions, both of them I am not sure are possible, and which of the two would be better. Also, I do think there could be a better solution.

1. Start the dashboard at a specific time and write away a csv with the required information. I don't know how to put the input values to the right settings though (they would be different from the normal initial settings). Hopefully start this without a visible endpoint (headless chromedriver for example).
2. Within Shiny, do a check if it's a specific time. If that's the case, change all inputs to the right settings, and export/do something with the required values. I don't prefer this, as there will be users using the dashboard at that time, and I don't want to disturb their work.

To give a bit more context, I would like to obtain values/dataframes from several dashboards at a specific time. These values are calculated via a chain of multiple reactives and inputs. I cannot trust that these dashboards are already running, so I need to start them.

Comment: If you don't want the dashboard to be open or visible, why do you need shiny? Why don't you just make a script that runs at certain time? You're the one that enters the inputs, right?

Comment: @bretauv good question, I haven't made that explicit in my question I see. The dashboards are combining several data sources and doing some calculations. The outcome is shown to users in the dashboard. I want to see the outcome of the calculations at a certain point in time. I _could_ recreate all these calculations in a new R/python script, or rewrite the dashboards in such a way that all of the calculations are done in functions.